# Testing for Zero or Positive Whole Number

Tags: bash

How can I test whether a number in a `bash` script is `0` (zero) or a positive whole number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common idiom for that is to check if the variable's value consists of nothing but numbers. With newer bash shells, you can use `=~` and a regular expression:

```bash
zero_or_positive_integer(){
    for i in "$@"; do
        if [[ "$i" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
            echo "YES $i is either 0 or a positive integer"
        else
            echo "NO $i is neither 0 nor a positive integer"
        fi
    done
}
```

Which results in:

```
$ zero_or_positive_integer foo -2 1.5 0 12
NO foo is neither 0 nor a positive integer
NO -2 is neither 0 nor a positive integer
NO 1.5 is neither 0 nor a positive integer
YES 0 is either 0 or a positive integer
YES 12 is either 0 or a positive integer
```

Answer (score 4):

To do tests, you typically use the `[` or `[[` operator. `[` is a synonym for the command `test` (not part of Bash specifically)

```
$ help [
[: [ arg... ]
    Evaluate conditional expression.
    
    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
    be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

```
$ man test
[...]
       INTEGER1 -eq INTEGER2
              INTEGER1 is equal to INTEGER2
       INTEGER1 -ge INTEGER2
              INTEGER1 is greater than or equal to INTEGER2
[...]
```

So it looks like you can write (don't forget spaces -- `[` is just a built-in program, so keep its arguments separate)

```
if [ "$var" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Zero"
elif [ "$var" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Positive"
fi
```

Note that if `$var` is not an integer, this will result in an error. We're assuming `$var` is some integer already.

If you're not sure that `$var` is an integer, I'm not aware of a great test, so here's some code using regular expressions:

```
if [[ "$var" =~ ^[1-9][0-9]+$ ]]; then
  echo "Positive"
elif [[ "$var" = 0 ]]; then
  echo "Zero"
else
  echo "Other"
fi
```

Comment: Actually, `[` _is_ part of the bash shell since bash provides it as a builtin. It's just that there is also another `[`, often found at `/usr/bin/[` which is a standalone executable and mandated by POSIX. However, unless you call it explicitly by running `/usr/bin/[`, you will never see it since shell builtins take priority. You can confirm this by running `type [` and `type -a [`. The `help` message you show (and all `help` messages since `help` is a bash thing) is about the builtin, very much a part of bash.

Answer (score 2):

The `printf` Bash built-in will read a string and verify that it can be successfully converted as specified by the format string. You can check the status "${?}", use `-v` to put the value into a temporary variable, and discard the error message with `2>/dev/null`.

```
$ a=-56
$ printf -v q '%d' "${a}"; echo $? "${q}"
0 -56
$ a=-56.3
$ printf -v q '%d' "${a}"; echo $? "${q}"
bash: printf: -56.3: invalid number
1 -56
$ a=315.8e4
$ printf -v q '%d' "${a}"; echo $? "${q}"
bash: printf: 315.8e4: invalid number
1 315
$ printf -v q '%f' "${a}"; echo $? "${q}"
0 3158000.000000
```

Comment: I think you misread the question: the OP wants the test to succeed only on 0 and _positive_ integers but your (otherwise really neat!) approach also returns success for negative integers.